# How can I use async/await while assigning a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have a variable I'm setting based on the result of an async function, the variable is `initialState`

```
const initialState = await getContacts()
  .then((body) => {
    console.log('body: ');
    console.log(body);
    return body;
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

My getContacts() returns a promise that should be the result of this function:

```
export async function getContacts() {
  let data = fetch('/api/contacts').then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return data.json();
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));

  return data;
}
```

I think part of my problem might be that I'm trying to call this from a plain javascript file. It is actually the index.js of my React application. I'm fetching some sort of initial state of my app from the DB before I load up the app. I should move this code and clean it up quite a bit, but I was trying to get a quick and dirty test up and running. I'm getting a compiler error:

`SyntaxError: \contacts\client\index.js: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`

My index.js that contains the await is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { getContacts } from './server/api';

const initialState = await getContacts()
  .then((body) => {
    console.log('body: ');
    console.log(body);
    return body;
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));

console.log('initial state: ');
console.log(initialState);

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({});
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ createStore(reducers, initialState, composeEnhancers(
  )) }>
   <App />
  </Provider>
, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Comment: Is this related to your previous question?  [why-is-my-function-returning-a-promise-and-not-an-object-from-my-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507439/why-is-my-function-returning-a-promise-and-not-an-object-from-my-db/55507900#55507900)

Comment: You are using await while setting initialState which is wrong. As the error suggests, await can be used only inside async function. Check @doublesharp's answer below. Its legit.

Comment: @jtabuloc yep. But the problem before was that my backend endpoint was not working, there was an issue with my webpack dev server.

Comment: @VishalGulati when I do that I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined` error. I think this is due to using async/await in React? At least that was what I found last time I ran into this issue.

Comment: @intA Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33527883/5346095

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the call to `getContacts()` in an async function - you also don't want to mix up `async/await` with `.then()`,

```
(async function() {
  const contacts = await getContacts();
  console.log('contacts', contacts);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption that attempting to call the asynchronous `getContacts()` function with an `await` is part of the issue with your code. In order to make a call to a function like `await getContacts(){}` you need to have that code wrapped in an asynchronous function that is defined like:

```
async function wrapperFunction() {
    const contacts = await getContacts()
    console.log('body: ')
    console.log(contacts)
}
```

Also, if you want to execute this function and also add some error handling logic you can do this:

```
wrapperFunction().catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

The `contacts` variable would then be your initial state as well to pass to your Redux store `createStore()` function call.

It is possible to mix the two since they are both syntaxes for handling asynchronous logic, but you just need to assemble usage of the two together properly. I suggest reading through the Mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) on async functions to get a good idea of how to use async/await as well as how you can use this convention with the Promise syntax as well.

Answer (score -2):

You cant use await if not in an async function declaration.

Maybe this can work:

```
const initialState = async () => {
  try {
    await getContacts();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
console.log('initial state: ');
console.log(initialState);
```

You are missing the point of async/await mixing it with .then()

You don't need then, because await returns a solved promise.

Comment: I get a `index.js?1942:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined` now. I believe this is due to using async/await in React, I tried a similar implementation before but couldn't get it to work in React with async/await.

Comment: That is setting `initialState` to a `Promise` by assigning it to an `async` function. When you `console.log` it will not be the result of `getContacts()`, it will be the unresolved promise.